# Dúvida com Gatilho de Update em Tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server, pl-sql

Tenho duas tabelas, perguntas e respostas, é gostaria de atualiza as mesmas de acordo com o que for selecionado: Banco Sql Server 2005

Problema:

```html
--usuário excluindo a pergunta (não está gravando a data da exclusão é não está excluindo as perguntas)
update TB_PERGUNTA set EXCLUIR_PERGUNTA = 'S' where IDPERGUNTA = 4 and IDUSUARIO = 1


--moderador excluindo a pergunta (não está gravando a data da exclusão é não está excluindo as perguntas)
update TB_PERGUNTA set BLOQUEIO_PERGUNTA = 'S' where IDPERGUNTA = 4 and IDMODERADOR = 7
```

```html
Create table [TB_PERGUNTA]
(
    [IDPERGUNTA] Integer NOT NULL, UNIQUE ([IDPERGUNTA]),
    [IDCATEGORIA] Integer NOT NULL,
    [IDUSUARIO] Integer NOT NULL,
    [IDMODERADOR] Integer NOT NULL,
    [TITULO_PERGUNTA] Text NULL,
    [DESCRICAO_PERGUNTA] Text NULL,
    [BLOQUEIO_PERGUNTA] Char(1) NULL,
    [DESCRICAO_BLOQUEIO] Text NULL,
    [EXCLUIR_PERGUNTA] Char(1) NULL,
    [DATA_PERGUNTA] Datetime NULL,
    [DATA_EXCLUIR] Datetime NULL,
Primary Key ([IDPERGUNTA])
) 
go

Create table [TB_RESPOSTA]
(
    [IDRESPOSTA] Integer NOT NULL, UNIQUE ([IDRESPOSTA]),
    [IDPERGUNTA] Integer NOT NULL,
    [IDUSUARIO] Integer NOT NULL,
    [IDMODERADOR] Integer NOT NULL,
    [RESPOSTA] Text NULL,
    [RESPOSTA_SELECIONADA] Char(1) NULL,
    [NOTA_RESPOSTA] Numeric(3,2) NULL,
    [BLOQUEIO_RESPOSTA] Char(1) NULL,
    [DESCRICAO_BLOQUEIO] Text NULL,
    [DATA_RESPOSTA] Datetime NULL,
    [DATA_EXCLUIR] Datetime NULL,
Primary Key ([IDRESPOSTA],[IDPERGUNTA])
) 
go
```

Tenho a Trigger:

```html
--gatilho para atualiza a tabela de pergunta é resposta no caso de exclusão pelo usuário
--ou pelo moderador
CREATE TRIGGER TGR_TB_PERGUNTA_UPDATE
 ON [dbo].[TB_PERGUNTA]
 FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @EXCLUIRPERGUNTA CHAR
   DECLARE @BLOQUEIOPERGUNTA CHAR
   DECLARE @IDPERGUNTA INT
   DECLARE @IDUSUARIO INT
   DECLARE @IDMODERADOR INT

   --se o excluirpergunta receber (S) então o usuário está bloqueando a pergunta se (N) está abrindo a pergunta
   SELECT  @EXCLUIRPERGUNTA  = EXCLUIR_PERGUNTA  FROM TB_PERGUNTA INSERTED
   --se o bloqueiopergunta receber (S) então o moderador está bloqueando a pergunta se (N) está abrindo a pergunta
   SELECT  @BLOQUEIOPERGUNTA = BLOQUEIO_PERGUNTA FROM TB_PERGUNTA INSERTED
   --pega o ID da pergunta
   SELECT  @IDPERGUNTA       = IDPERGUNTA        FROM TB_PERGUNTA INSERTED
   --pega o id do usuário
   SELECT  @IDUSUARIO        = IDUSUARIO         FROM TB_PERGUNTA INSERTED
   --pega o id do moderador
   SELECT  @IDMODERADOR      = IDMODERADOR       FROM TB_PERGUNTA INSERTED   

    --pergunta excluida pelo usuário 
   IF ( @EXCLUIRPERGUNTA = 'S')
    BEGIN
      --excluir a pergunta
     UPDATE TB_PERGUNTA  SET  EXCLUIR_PERGUNTA = 'S', 
            DESCRICAO_BLOQUEIO = 'Excluido pelo usuário' ,
            DATA_EXCLUIR = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 20)
            WHERE IDPERGUNTA = @IDPERGUNTA AND IDUSUARIO =  @IDUSUARIO 

          --excluir todas as respostas referente a pergunta
     UPDATE TB_RESPOSTA SET BLOQUEIO_RESPOSTA = 'S', 
            DATA_EXCLUIR = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 20),
            DESCRICAO_BLOQUEIO = 'Excluido pelo usuário'  WHERE IDPERGUNTA = @IDPERGUNTA          
    END

    --pergunta bloqueada pelo moderador
   IF ( @BLOQUEIOPERGUNTA = 'S')
    BEGIN
     --excluir pergunta
     UPDATE TB_PERGUNTA  SET BLOQUEIO_PERGUNTA = 'S', 
          DESCRICAO_BLOQUEIO = 'Está pergunta foi bloqueada pelo moderador',  
          DATA_EXCLUIR = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 20)
          WHERE IDPERGUNTA = @IDPERGUNTA AND IDMODERADOR =  @IDMODERADOR

          --excluir respostas
     UPDATE TB_RESPOSTA SET BLOQUEIO_RESPOSTA = 'S', 
         DATA_EXCLUIR = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 20),
         DESCRICAO_BLOQUEIO = 'Excluido pelo moderador'  
         WHERE IDPERGUNTA = @IDPERGUNTA  

    END

    --pergunta aberta pelo usuário 
   IF ( @EXCLUIRPERGUNTA = 'N')
    BEGIN
      --pergunta aberta pelo usuário 
     UPDATE TB_PERGUNTA  SET  EXCLUIR_PERGUNTA = 'N', 
            DESCRICAO_BLOQUEIO = 'Excluido pelo usuário' , 
            DATA_EXCLUIR = null
            WHERE IDPERGUNTA = @IDPERGUNTA 
            AND IDUSUARIO =  @IDUSUARIO  

       --abre todas as respostas    
     UPDATE TB_RESPOSTA SET BLOQUEIO_RESPOSTA = 'N',
           DATA_EXCLUIR =null,
           DESCRICAO_BLOQUEIO = null 
           WHERE IDPERGUNTA = @IDPERGUNTA          
    END

    --pergunta aberta pelo moderador
   IF ( @BLOQUEIOPERGUNTA = 'N')
    BEGIN
     --abre a pergunta pelo moderador
     UPDATE TB_PERGUNTA  SET BLOQUEIO_PERGUNTA = 'N', 
            DESCRICAO_BLOQUEIO =null, 
            DATA_EXCLUIR =null
            WHERE IDPERGUNTA = @IDPERGUNTA 
            AND IDMODERADOR =  @IDMODERADOR

      --abre todas as respostas pelo moderador
     UPDATE TB_RESPOSTA SET BLOQUEIO_RESPOSTA = 'N', 
           DATA_EXCLUIR = null, 
           DESCRICAO_BLOQUEIO =null  
           WHERE IDPERGUNTA = @IDPERGUNTA  
           AND IDMODERADOR =  @IDMODERADOR  
    END

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repare que você está gerando uma recursiva com está trigger, veja:

Exemplo a variável @BLOQUEIOPERGUNTA está como "S", neste caso você irá gerar um update novamente na tabela assim ativando novamente a trigger, isso poderá ocasionar problemas, será necessário utilizar o comando TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL, que verifica quantas vezes a trigger foi executada por ela mesma, segue exemplo para sua trigger:

```
   DECLARE @EXCLUIRPERGUNTA CHAR
   DECLARE @BLOQUEIOPERGUNTA CHAR
   DECLARE @IDPERGUNTA INT
   DECLARE @IDUSUARIO INT
   DECLARE @IDMODERADOR INT
   --Caso a trigger esteja chamando a si mesma a execução é interrompida com o comando RETURN
   IF ( SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL ( ) ) >= 2 
     return

   --se o excluirpergunta receber (S) então o usuário está bloqueando a pergunta se (N) está abrindo a pergunta
```

Comment: Muito bom, perfeito, era isso mesmo. muito grato!